# Xamarin SignaturePad - Loading points for a code generated SignaturePadView vs XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm storing SignaturePad Points to a database with the intent to extract and store to PDF. Got it working, with the exception of adding points to the SignaturePadView object.

To add points, I am simply using signaturePad.Points = points. This approach works fine when inserting into a XAML SignaturePad element that displays to screen... but storing to a code generated Object results in a zero array length.

My code with both scenarios is below.

**My question is:**
am I missing a step when trying to assign points to a code generated SignaturePadView, and / or Is the fact that I am not rendering to screen (storing direct to PDF) a potential issue

**XAML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:H1PaperlessApp"
            xmlns:forms="clr-namespace:SignaturePad.Forms;assembly=SignaturePad.Forms"
            x:Class="H1PaperlessApp.Views.Temppage"
            Padding="10">    
    <StackLayout>    
        <forms:SignaturePadView x:Name="PadView"
                            HeightRequest="150"
                            WidthRequest="240"
                            BackgroundColor="White"
                            StrokeColor="Black"
                            StrokeWidth="2"/>    
        <forms:SignaturePadView x:Name="ClonePadView"
                            HeightRequest="150"
                            WidthRequest="240"
                            BackgroundColor="White"
                            StrokeColor="Black"
                            StrokeWidth="2"/>    
        <Button Text="Save" FontSize="30" BackgroundColor="DodgerBlue" TextColor="White"
            Clicked="SaveButton_Clicked"/>    
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

**Code Behind (Cloning from one XAML Generated element to another). In this case, the second Points is set correctly**

```
private async void SaveButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var pnts = PadView.Points.ToArray(); // pnts = {Xamarin.Forms.Point[294]}
    var originalPoints = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(pnts);
    Xamarin.Forms.Point[] points = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Xamarin.Forms.Point[]>(originalPoints);
    ClonePadView.Points = points; // ClonePadView.Points = {Xamarin.Forms.Point[294]}
    Stream img = await ClonePadView.GetImageStreamAsync(SignatureImageFormat.Png);  
}
```

**Code Behind (Creating the target SignaturePadView via code. note that the second points has a count of 0)**

```
private async void SaveButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var pnts = PadView.Points.ToArray();  // pnts = {Xamarin.Forms.Point[294]}
    var originalPoints = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(pnts);
    Xamarin.Forms.Point[] points = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Xamarin.Forms.Point[]>(originalPoints);
    SignaturePadView CodeClonePadView = new SignaturePadView { };
    CodeClonePadView.Points = points;  // ClonePadView.Points = {Xamarin.Forms.Point[0]}
    Stream img = await CodeClonePadView.GetImageStreamAsync(SignatureImageFormat.Png);
}
```

Comment: I have fixed mine in Xamarin.iOS by invoking the assignment in UI thread. In Xamarin.Android, this solution doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe you should add the code created signature view into the layout first? Otherwise how is it suposed to render anything?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, a SignaturePadView must be visible and rendered in order to set its Points or Strokes. You can do this in the page's Appearing event.

Here's the XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="SignaturePadPOC.MainPage" Appearing="MainPage_OnAppearing">

    <StackLayout x:Name="MyStackLayout">
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Here's the code behind:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public Point[][] Strokes { get; set; } // Set this prior to the appearing event;
    private SignaturePadView signatureView;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        signatureView = new SignaturePadView
        {
            BackgroundColor = Color.White,
            StrokeColor = Color.Black,
            StrokeWidth = 3
        };
        MyStackLayout.Children.Add(signatureView);
    }

    private void MainPage_OnAppearing(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        signatureView.Strokes = Strokes;
    }
}
```